# Shopify Webhooks not redirect into Laravel Route

Tags: laravel, shopify, webhooks, shopify-api

I have added laravel route as callback url in my shopify webhook (product/create).

```
<domain>./webhook/product/create
```

And my route is

```
Route::post('/webhook/product/create', function(){
    Log::info('Hey!');
});
```

When I send test notification from shopify, it is not printing log.
It is working fine with (redirect correctly) public/product.php, but I need it in laravel route.

I want shopify webhook response into my laravel function.

Comment: Double-check laravel.log for any errors. Do the post with Postman, see if your command gets executed then

Comment: @UnderDog Yes, I checked it. Also, I got the solution by disabling csrf token verification for the particular route.

Comment: Ok, answer your own question, then you can mark it as an answer. Great job on finding your solution!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by disabling csrf token verification for the particular route.